# Write the equation $7z^2=8x^2+8y^2$ in spherical form

Tags: spherical-coordinates

> How can i write the equation $7z^2=8x^2+8y^2$ in spherical form

What i try

Put $x=\rho\sin \phi \cos \theta$ and $y=\rho\cos\phi\cos\theta$ and $z=\rho\cos\phi$

So equation is

$$7\rho^2\cos^2\phi=8\rho^2\sin^2\phi$$

$$\tan^2\phi=\frac{7}{8}$$

I did not understand how can i write above equation in spherical form because there are no $\rho$ present

Please also explain me is my answer is correct or not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your solution is correct. It is the equation of a conical surface with half angle $\phi$ from the $z$ axis.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. can i write $\rho=0$ and $\tan^2\phi=7/8$ simultaneously

Comment: Are you thinking something like this: $\rho(\tan^2\phi-7/8)=0$? So either $\rho =0$ or the square of the tangent is $7/8$

Comment: Yes exactly andrei...

Answer (score 1):

When you write $7\rho^2\cos^2\phi=8\sin^2\phi$ you missed $\rho$ on right, though final result is correct.

As $(\phi, \theta, \rho)$ is usual 3 dim space, then you have plane $\phi$ = const. It is well known  [Conical surface](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Conical_surface) in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates.

Comment: constant $\phi$ is a conical surface, not a plane (unless $\phi=\pi/2$)

Comment: Thanks zkutch. Can i write $\rho=0$ and $\tan^2\phi=7/8$ simultaneously

Comment: In $\tan^2\phi=7/8$ you have all values for $\theta, \rho$ and, so $0$ for any. @Andrei. Added to answer - your sentence is correct in ($x,y,z$). This is not in contradiction with plane(s) in $(\phi, \theta, \rho)$, it is beauty of changing coordinates.

Comment: @zkutch plz see my doubt.Thanks

Comment: Plane(s)  is $\tan^2\phi=7/8$, $\left(\phi=\pm \arctan ( \pm \frac{\sqrt{14}}{4})\right)$. So which doubt you have with $\rho=0$? Intersection of two perpendicular planes should be line.